# Macro to save Excel sheet with file name and path from cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro button that will save the active sheet as a pdf, go to a specific folder(based on cell value), and have a file name based on cell value. What would be the VBA code to save a the active excel sheet based on values in a cell?

Example:

(First part of Path name)
C:\User\Documents\

The final part of the path will be the folder name which is in cell B2.

The file name I need to auto create as "Value of B1 + XXXXX(static text) + Value of D2"

Example Output

Save to: C:\User\Documents*Folder Name from B1*

File Name: *Text from B1* + "Settlement WE" + *Value from D2*

Please help.

Comment: Use `&` to concatenate all the parts together.

Comment: You would just concat your relevant values using static strings and range references. What code/attempt to you have to share?

Comment: You will need to check if the path name ends in "\" as well.

Answer (score 1):

To create your file name:

```
Dim vn as String, fn as String

vn = "some string"
fn = Range("B1") & vn & Range("D2")
```

---

`fn` would be your final output *(unclear if D2 includes file extension or not)*